# How to let a user hit the NEXT key and jump to the next `UITextField` within a ScrollView

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have several `UITextFields`, my keyboard has a "NEXT" key as the return key. I'd like to let the user hit the NEXT key and jump to the next `UITextField`. I read online that the best way to do that would be to implement the function:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

I did this however it is not working for me.

Please see my .m file

```
#import "customerInfoViewController.h"

@implementation customerInfoViewController
@synthesize infoModel;

@synthesize Name;
@synthesize AptNum;
@synthesize Street1;
@synthesize Street2;
@synthesize City;
@synthesize Telephone;
@synthesize Email1;


@synthesize textFieldBeingEdited;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize doneButton; 

CartSingleton *Cart;
//==============================================================================
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:nil/*self.view.window*/];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    Cart = [CartSingleton getSingleton];


}
//==============================================================================
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                  object:nil];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}
//==============================================================================
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
        NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    textFieldBeingEdited = textField;
}
//==============================================================================
-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
        NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    textFieldBeingEdited = NULL;
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    if (moveViewUp) 
       {
        [self scrollTheView:NO];
       }

}
//==============================================================================
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    NSLog(@"TextField tag is, %d ", textField.tag);
if ([self.Name isFirstResponder]) 
   {
    [self.AptNum becomeFirstResponder];
   }
if ([self.AptNum isFirstResponder]) 
   {
    [self.Street1 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
if ([self.Street1 isFirstResponder])
   {
    [self.Street2 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
if ([self.Street2 isFirstResponder])
   {
    [self.City becomeFirstResponder];
   }
if ([self.City isFirstResponder])
   {
    [self.Telephone becomeFirstResponder];
   }
if ([self.Telephone isFirstResponder])
   {
    [self.Email1 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
if ([self.Email1 isFirstResponder])
   {
    [self.Email1 resignFirstResponder];
   }
return YES;
}
//==============================================================================
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{

    NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
NSDictionary *info = [notif userInfo];
NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
//NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;
float bottomPoint = (textFieldBeingEdited.frame.origin.y + textFieldBeingEdited.frame.size.height /*+ 20*/);
scrollAmount = keyboardSize.height - (self.view.frame.size.height- bottomPoint);
/*
 CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
 viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;
 scrollView.frame = viewFrame;
 */
if(scrollAmount > 0)
   {
    moveViewUp = YES;
    [self scrollTheView:YES];
   }
else 
   {
    moveViewUp = NO;
   }

}
//==============================================================================
-(void)scrollTheView:(BOOL)movedUp
{
        NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if(movedUp)
       {
        rect.origin.y -=scrollAmount;
       }
    else 
       {
        rect.origin.y +=scrollAmount;
       }
    self.view.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


//==============================================================================
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);

    scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;

    textFieldBeingEdited = NULL;
    //If there is already 
    if (Cart.customerInfoObtained)
       {
        self.Name.text = Cart.customerInfo.Name;
        self.AptNum.text = Cart.customerInfo.AptNo;
        self.Street1.text = Cart.customerInfo.Street1;
        self.Street2.text = Cart.customerInfo.Street2;
        self.City.text = Cart.customerInfo.City;
        self.Telephone.text = Cart.customerInfo.Tel;
        self.Email1.text = Cart.customerInfo.Email;     
       }

}

//==============================================================================
-(IBAction)doneButtonPressed
{
    NSLog(@"Done button pressed ");
        NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    /*
    infoModel = [[customerInfoModel alloc] initWithObjects:self.Name.text
                                                     AptNo:self.AptNum.text
                                                   Street1:self.Street1.text
                                                   Street2:self.Street2.text
                                                      City:self.City.text
                                                       Tel:self.Telephone.text
                                                     Email:self.Email1.text]; 


    [Cart addCustomerInfo:infoModel];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    */
}


//==============================================================================
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}
//==============================================================================
- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
        NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
//==============================================================================

- (void)dealloc 
{
    NSLog(@"deallocating %@",self);
    [scrollView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
//==============================================================================

@end
```

I am stepping through the function:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

and here is the Consoleoutput

```
TextField tag is, 6 
[customerInfoViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:]

[customerInfoViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:]

[customerInfoViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:]

[customerInfoViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:]

[customerInfoViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:]

[customerInfoViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:]
```

Comment: When asking questions, it is not a good idea to paste a wall of code. Just provide enough code to make your point. That way you are more likely to attract the attentions of other users who are experts in your field. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things, first if the `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` is not being fired first make sure that the text fields have something like name.delegate=self;

Second, if the cursor is moving to the next field you will need to implement the

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Also, if the part of the scrollview is below the keyboard when you display the keyboard you will want to shrink the height of the scrollview so the keyboard does not overlap.

Comment: +1 Yup, the missing delegate is HIGHLY likely to be the cause of that code not firing.

Comment: In my viewDidLoad, I added these linesself.Name.delegate = self;
 self.AptNum.delegate = self;
 self.Street1.delegate = self;
 self.Street2.delegate = self;
 self.City.delegate = self;
 self.Telephone.delegate = self;
 self.Email1.delegate = self;

But that did not seem to work. Keyboard's Next button still doesnothing :(

Comment: So the function does work apparently so its not a delegate issue......i stepped through the function -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField . I have edited my post above to add some console output....Im trying to debug. Please help

Comment: is the focus being set to the next field?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {    // called when "Next" is pressed
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn");
    if (textField == nameField) {
        [streetAddressField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == streetAddressField) {
        [cityField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == cityField) {
        [stateField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == stateField) {
        [zipField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Steps:

*1)Conform to the UITextFieldDelegate*

```
 @interface ViewControllerTest :UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUserId;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;

@end
```

*2)Assign the textfield delegate to current viewcontroller*

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];


  self.txtUserId.delegate=self;

  self.txtUserId.tag=1;


  self.txtPassword.delegate=self;

  self.txtPassword.tag=2;
 }
```

*3)Implement the textFieldShouldReturn method*

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if(textField.tag==1)
  {
     [self.txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```